# How to create (or where to look) a display and editor templates for XElement class (MVC4, Razor)

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model with XElement fields (some of these could not be null) like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public XElement Data { get; set; } // could not be null
    public XElement Scheme { get; set; } // could be null
    // other fields
}
```

How I can specify display and editor templates for XElement-fields of this model?
Field for edit value of XElement field must be look like multiline string. User just past in field some XML-text, like

```
<Element1 attr1="artrValue1" attr2="attrValue2">
    <SubElement1>
        <!-- Other elements -->
    </SubElement1>
    <SubElement2 />
    <!-- Other elements -->
</Element1>
```

And this text must be convert to XElement value (XDocument.Parse(string).Root)

I am working with Razor MVC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put custom editor templates to `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` and display templates to `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` directories, the framework will pick up them automatically.
In your case, you need to create `XElement.cshtml` file:

```
@model System.Xml.Linq.XELement
@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, Model == null ? string.Empty : Model.ToString())
```

After that `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sheme)` will render custom template.

If you want to automatically populate `XElement` fields with posted values, consider creating a custom model binder:

```
public class XElementModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        return value == null ? null : XElement.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

and register it in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(XElement), new XElementModelBinder());
}
```